# Given $n = ab$ with $a,b$ unknown what are some good choices for $a_0, d$ such that $a,b$ are both in the AP $a_0 + kd$

Tags: arithmetic-progressions, distribution-of-primes

**Problem:** Given $n = ab > 0$ with $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ unknown, what are some *good* choices for $a_0, d$ such that $a,b$ are both in the AP $a_0 + kd$? We are not making any assumptions about $a,b$ being prime. So, we need to consider all divisors.

Obvious choices are

$$
(a_0,d) = 
\begin{cases}
  (1,2), & \text{if $n$ is odd}, \\
  (0,1), & \text{$\forall n$}, \\
  (1,1), & \text{$\forall n$}. \\
\end{cases}
$$

The second and third formulations are the same AP and are equivalent.

Therefore, a *good* choice would be the pair $(a_0, d)$ such that $d > 2$. Are there other choices that depend on $n$, perhaps based on modular conditions etc.,?

Comment: What do you mean by "good choices"?

Comment: @jjagmath, I've edited the question to focus on choices $d>2$ as good ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, $a$ and $b$ are in the arithmetic progression $c+kd$ if and only if $d\mid a-b$ and $c\equiv a \pmod d$. This gives all the solutions.